# Can't connect Arabic Letters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I was trying to add an animation on the logo it works fine but once
the animation starts it  looks like this:

[image: Arabic Script Animation Frame]

While I was searching, I found an article where they said to write `&zwj;`, but it made no difference!

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this.

In the JavaScript code there was this line:

```js
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
```

I added `&zwj;` to the span:

```js
replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&&zwj;</span>");
```

This fixed the issue, but the browser started to crash.

Is there any solution to fix this?